# How do I make a lot of money?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I always find myself in a situation where I don't have enough money for the things I want. Be it for weapons or armor or even for smaller stuff like re-stocking on consumables.

How can I guarantee a steady income of zenny so I don't have to worry about money anymore?

Comment: your point about restocking on consumables raises a question to me. Are you buying stock of items from the shop in-game? If so, that's a no-no. go gather and craft!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fortunately there are a few options to make money without even grinding too much for it. Some of those options are available from the very beginning while others will be unlocked in later stages of the game. Here are some methods ordered by the time in the game you can unlock them.

### High-Profit Investigations

**Unlocked by:** Completing quests/Killing small monsters
**Availability:** As soon as investigations are unlocked (start of the game)
**Profit:** Medium-High
**Time required:** Low-Medium
**Passive or active:** Active
**Pro:** Available from the very start of the game, you gain extra materials per quest completed.
**Con:** Actively requires you to do a special quest, investigations don't always show up (RNG)

**How it works:** Keep an eye out for investigations that have an increased zenny reward (marked with an exclamation mark next to the reward). Often those quests require you to slay 5-15 small monsters which can be done in under 5 minutes. You can also use one of your log-in vouchers on these quests to double the amount of Zenny gained.

### Cultivating Might Seeds

**Unlocked by:** Completing optional Botanical quests up until "Persistent Pests"
**Availability:** Mid Low-Rank
**Profit:** Low-Medium
**Time required:** Medium
**Passive or active:** Passive
**Pro:** Early availability, requires one time setup and is passive after that

**Con:** Only mediocre Zenny rewards, takes up a cultivation slot

**How it works:** Might seeds have been a popular money making method in previous titles of the series and remain so in World. The method is simple: You cultivate might seeds that sell for 140 zenny each and you complete quests normally. Using fertilizer will further increase your profit.

### Bandit Mantle

**Unlocked by:** Completing the optional quest "Redefining the Power Couple"
**Availability:** Late Low-Rank
**Profit:** High-Very high
**Time required:** None
**Passive or active:** Passive
**Pro:** High income, passive method, income increases with monster difficulty

**Con:** You sacrifice a tool-slot (Defense, Utility)

**How it works:** By far the most efficient money-making method in MH:World is the Bandit mantle. You can equip the tool on a hunt and it causes your attacks against a monster to sometimes drop a trade-in item as a shiny drop. These items can then be sold for anywhere between 1000 and 5000 zenny per piece. At the start of high rank you can expect somewhere around 10000 zenny extra per quest if you use the mantle and this amount increases the further you progress into the game. A great thing is also that it's completely passive if you are hunting big monsters (which is what you should be doing most of the time).

### The Argosy

**Unlocked by:** Reaching High-Rank
**Availability:** High-Rank
**Profit:** High
**Time required:** Low
**Passive or active:** Passive
**Pro:** High income, passive method

**Con:** Costs a decent chunk of resource points

**How it works:** The moment you reach high-rank the Argosy will be available. It's a ship you can send out to gather materials which you can then buy for resource points. Here you can choose the option to buy trade-in items. Every 3 quests you complete the Argosy returns and you will be able to buy whatever you've ordered. This is essentially trading excess resource-points for Zenny.

**As a general tip regarding trade-in items:** If you sort your item-box (R3 on PS4) they will always show up on the last page and are labelled with "Trade-In". Those items can be sold without much thought and are only in the game to fill your pockets.

Comment: And never forget to go into your box and clean out all those old, spare monster parts you aren't using! If you're farming for a gem odds are you have lots of zenny worth of extras.

Comment: @Zodack I actually didn't include that method since back when I did that I often found myself in a situation where I only *thought* I wouldn't need those items anymore. Especially when trying out new weapons.

Comment: @Justchge I usually only sell half when I have 20-25+ of a part. I definitely understand selling bulk and then later needing those exact parts for something up the weapon tree.

Comment: Additionally, use your vouchers. they double your zenny reward at the end of the quest.

Comment: If you use Bandit Mantle, make sure to run dual blades as the drop chance for an item is per hit and seems to be the same for every weapon. With dual blades I can easily get up to 20 drops in 1 quest

Comment: To expand on your tip about trade in items, you can also press Y or Triangle while in the Item Box to automatically sell all trade in items.